# What was wrong with my edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

What was wrong with this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/833263)? It seemed like a straightforward one...

Comment: I would have approved this without giving it a second thought. Not sure what the Community bot saw that was so worth rejecting... :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like what happened is that [the current author of the 2nd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12966499/2) opted to "improve" your edit and unchecked the "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox on that page.

The quotes around `improve` are intentional since that's what the button's called *and* I'm not sure it was an *actual* improvement, nevermind one worth rejecting your edit over.

So, good news: you did nothing wrong that I can see. I would've approved your edit as well.

Bad news: there's nothing we can do about the rejected edit beyond just making the changes that were lost as the result again (which I'm about to do).

Comment: Personally I uncheck that checkbox if the person making the suggestion could have done a whole lot better than they did. Having said that, I personally would have approved the linked edit (and I'm hard to please).

Comment: @slugster I'm certainly not advocating always leaving it checked. :)